# About Definition: Rewriting Algorithm from Go Code to C

Tags: c, algorithm, go

Currently translating weighted DAG to C code which is written in Go language and topologically sorted. Actually I missed one part of the code that is the function below sample. I couldn't get what "visit" declaration is. Is it function declaration within another function ? If you explain in C syntax that would be great.

```
func (g *graph) topoSort() []int {
    result := make([]int, g.size())
    marks := make([]bool, g.size())
    resultIndex := g.size() - 1

    var visit func(int)
    visit = func(u int) {
        for _, item := range g.adjList[u] {
            if !marks[item.vertex] {
                visit(item.vertex)
            }
        }

        marks[u] = true
        result[resultIndex] = u
        resultIndex--
    }

    for u := range g.adjList {
        if !marks[u] {
            visit(u)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a local function definition, and it [closes over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) `marks`, which makes it not worth translating directly. You can transform it to an ordinary static function if you also change it to take `marks` as an argument.